# RecyclerView Item Template

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have been struggeling the last 2 hours to get the layout of an RecycleView working the way I want it to. Basically all I want is that three items of the RecycleView fit onto one screen width, like this: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDa7s.png)
Where each of the boxes contains the image.

This is what it currently produces:
[Current State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCpep.jpg)

This is what I got:

listitem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:rowCount="5"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="4"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowSpan="5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="4"
                android:layout_rowWeight="2"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />


            <CustomFontTextView
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="4"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Canada"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:autoSizeMinTextSize="24dp"
                android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="48dp"/>

            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="4"
                android:layout_rowWeight="2"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />


            <CustomFontTextView
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="4"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Canada"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#8Fffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:autoSizeMinTextSize="18dp"
                android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24dp"/>




        </GridLayout>



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the activity:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="activities.MainActivity"
    android:background="#f2f2f2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

That is almost what I wanted but the items are now sized based on the length of the description. Instead I want the description to wrap if needed. Can someone elaborate on why this is happening an how to fix it?

Comment: You might consider sharing the screen what you have got currently.

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why this is happening

You set the width of the RelativeLayout as wrap content. It makes the widh wrapped to the content as the name suggest.

> How to fix it

You have to change it to a fixed value, say `200dp`.

**Here are some other things I have noticed in the provided layout:**

- You should consider using `"match_parent"` instead of `"fill_parent"` because it is deprecated since API level 8.
- `layout_centerInParent="true"` have no effect in the `CardView` because it is already filled to the parent
- Remove the line `weightSum="3"` in the `CardView` because it won't work on `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Ok, makes sense :^) . But how do I realise the three items per screen thing with devices I do not know the screen width of?

Comment: If you strictly want 3 items per screen, I think you may have to do it using code. You have to find the width by measure the layout width and dividing iit by three (in such a way that it wont make problem with margin or padding)

Comment: you can restrict number of columns by adding `RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);` where 3 is the span count i.e number of columns

Comment: @Tabish I doubt if it work in this case. It looks like he is trying to arrange items linearly.